# unsafe keyword only check parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#, still struggling in understanding the use of unsafe. Let's say we have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   unsafe 
   {
      int myInt = 10;
      SquareIntPointer(&myInt );  //OK here, in unsafe context
   }
   int myInt2 = 5;
   SquareIntPointer(&myInt2);   // compile error, not in unsafe context
}

static unsafe void SquareIntPointer(int* myIntPointer)
{
   // Square the value just for a test.
   *myIntPointer *= *myIntPointer;
}
```

but if I change the code as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int myInt2 = 5;
   SquareIntPointer();   // OK here, but why?
}

static unsafe void SquareIntPointer()
{
   int random = 10;
   int* myIntPointer = &random;
   *myIntPointer *= *myIntPointer;
}
```

so we don't have any compile error here, but isn't that SquareIntPointer method is still dealing with pointer type in the method body? and doesn't mean only the parameter is checked to see if it is a pointer type? that would be a little bit stupid.

Comment: Sounds normal to me. [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) must "surround" everything that uses pointers like `&` and `*`.

Comment: If you are only new to C#, then you need to read the documentation which clearly states how to use it

Comment: In addition to what @UweKeim said; `// OK here, but why?` - because, sloppy speaking, none of the "unsafeness" is visible to the caller. It would have been the same if the unsafe method had only safe parameters, etc. It would have not been the same (as you have seen before) if the method itself needs an unsafe context to be invoked (e.g. has a pointer type parameter). The [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) has the rules.

Comment: My suggestion, if you are new to C#, is not to look at `unsafe` (it just isn't that important, particularly for a beginner). I've worked with C# for > 10 years. I've probably used `unsafe` once in those 10 years. The problem with using `unsafe` is it encourages you to think in terms of pointers etc - and for a new C# programmer, that is generally the wrong mindset to bring to the table. By putting `unsafe` to one side, you can focus on how idiomatic C# does things, as opposed to how C# allows C-style operations etc etc.

Comment: @UweKeim  but it did use '*' inside the method body

Comment: @slowjams Therefore, the `unsafe` signature in the declaration of the `SquareIntPointer` method. Again, this `unsafe` "surrounds" the pointer usage.

Comment: @UweKeim isn't that more nature that unsafe method cannot be used in non-unsafe context?

Comment: @slowjams I think the purpose of `unsafe` is mainly to remind the person writing the code that they are writing unsafe code, not to remind the callers that they are calling unsafe code, because that is an implementation detail that the callers don't need to know about.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using pointers as everything you did can be _safely_ done without them. In contrast to C, pointers are only used in very, very rare cases in C#.